# How to listen for HTTP events using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to create a Telegram bot using Spring framework. So, I decided it's a good idea to use a webhook.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook

But I don't know how to listen for incoming HTTP events on my computer. Could you explain me?

Comment: Hi Victor and welcome to Stackoverflow. Sadly this question is too broad for this community. You will need a "Spring REST-Resource" for your purpose, try googling around that topic. If you encounter specific difficulties feel free to post them as new questions.